# Jenkins: schedule a build at night after another project succeed

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests

My scenario is: I want to run a test suite after the production is updated, but not immediately after it builds successfully, but at midnight that day. (Cause the testing takes quite some resources and may cause our website temporarily unstable. )

Is there a way to set the trigger like this?

Comment: Rather than "Midnight", can it be "a fixed time after production updated" ?

Answer (score -1):

Create a job that will run automatically at midnight. Define a criteria in pre-build method